# Cannot provide null for an SObjectField custom metadata record field via Metadata API

Tags: metadata-api, custom-metadata

We're trying to update Custom Metadata records using the Custom Metadata API from Apex. The record has a field of type SObjectField. When we create we can omit this field and the result on the database is null as required. If we want to set the field to null by updated then we cannot omit it - that leaves it unchanged. If we send `null` explicitly then we get `INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST`.

How can we clear the field in an update?